# Get id from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select boxes whithin a form like this:

```
<form action="foo" method="post" id="form">
    <select id="one">
        <option value="foo1"></option>
        <option value="foo2"></option>
        <option value="foo3"></option>
      </select>
      <select id="two">
          <option value="bar1"></option>
          <option value="bar2"></option>
          <option value="bar3"></option>
      </select>
      <select id="three">
          <option value="baz1"></option>
          <option value="baz2"></option>
          <option value="baz3"></option>
      </select>
</form>
```

Now, if any of these three boxes change, I wanna know which one of them. I tried it like the following, but I only get the id of the first box. Do I have to write it for each select or is there a way to get the id of the changed select box?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').change(function() {    
        var strChosen = $('select').attr('id');    
        alert(strChosen);    
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *`this` keyword* and change your selector to `$('#form select')`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FG6xx/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form select').change(function() {
    var strChosen = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(strChosen);
  });
});
```

Note: You can also use `.on()` method for `change` *event* like

```
$('#form select').on('change',function() {});
```

For more information on the syntax, you can refer @sbaaaang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21039576/1542290)

Comment: on() wouldn't be better? :O

Comment: @sbaaaang Sure, I will go ahead with that

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah no problems just you know ... sometimes they return : "hey  wtf change() doesn't work"  and you must specify : "you need on() bla bla"  :D

Comment: _"For more information, you can refer @sbaaaang's answer"_, Which information? it's a only-code answer :)

Comment: @BlackSheep I should have written more code.. -sbaaang, it would be better if you add some explanation there

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the change handler for the `select` element then inside the handler use `this.id` to get the id of the select element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form select').change(function () {
        var strChosen = this.id;
        alert(strChosen);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MQUp6/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using .change() event on form. That's wrong.

Use select element with change event like below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').change(function() {

    var strChosen = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(strChosen);

  });
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/n46Be/

Answer (score 0):

first thing is that you need to bind the change event of the select box instead of form like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('select').change(function (e){        
   });    
});
```

then you are able to find the id of changed select box putting below code inside the change handler.

```
var selectedId = this.id;
```

the finale code look like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('select').change(function (e){
     var selectedId = this.id;
     alert(selectedId); 
   });    
});
```

thanks..